# Laravel 4 ERROR 500 After fresh install on LAMP

Tags: php, mysql, apache, .htaccess

This is my first time behind Ubuntu: I followed this tutorial to install `Apache, PHP, SQL and phpMyAdmin`. http://www.howtoforge.com/ubuntu_lamp_for_newbies

I got no errors and everything is working smooth. I then downloaded `composer.phar` and `laravel` I ran `php composer.phar install` and `php composer.phar update`. No errors here either I then changed apache config to have DirectoryROot at var/www/public.

And enabled rewrite mod: `sudo a2enmod rewrite`

Standard installation procedure however visiting localhost gives 0 php error messages only shows: Whoops, looks like something went wrong.

Apache error logs show nothing, access log only shows the 500 error. What am I missing I went over the entire procedure 3 times.

Answer (score -5):

I solved the problem.

1) Open Terminal
2) Navigate to your laravel root folder `CD var/www`
3) Execute `sudo chmod -R 777 *`

This solved the problem but be careful with this. Make sure your permissions are properly set when you move from local to live.

Comment: You don't need to set 777 permissions in every file. Just set in the `app/storage` folder. `sudo chmod -R 777 app/storage`.

Comment: My understanding is that 777 permissions are unsafe (too loose).  See http://stackoverflow.com/a/19302688/470749