# 403 Forbidden on laravel project, but nothing else

Tags: php, laravel, nginx, digital-ocean

I have a digital ocean droplet, I have a test page up on the root of the site, it works just fine, but when I am trying to connect to the laravel project, it hits me with a 403 Forbidden error.

Basically if I go to:

```
mysite.com/
```

it shows the normal page

and if I go to:

```
mysite.com/public
```

it shows me the `403 error`.

I have tried changing the permissions using `chmod -R 755 app/storage` even trying to change the permissions on the whole folder / directory and nothing works.

Here is the last part of the error log:

```
2014/12/22 11:13:02 [error] 14447#0: *1 directory index of "/var/www/mysite.com/public_html/" is forbidden, client: 41.150.139.252, server: mysite.com, request$
2014/12/22 11:13:07 [error] 14447#0: *2 directory index of "/var/www/mysite.com/public_html/" is forbidden, client: 41.150.139.252, server: mysite.com, request$
2014/12/22 11:15:29 [emerg] 14465#0: bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
2014/12/22 11:15:29 [emerg] 14465#0: bind() to [::]:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
2014/12/22 11:15:29 [emerg] 14465#0: bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
2014/12/22 11:15:29 [emerg] 14465#0: bind() to [::]:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
2014/12/22 11:15:29 [emerg] 14465#0: bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
2014/12/22 11:15:29 [emerg] 14465#0: bind() to [::]:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
2014/12/22 11:15:29 [emerg] 14465#0: bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
2014/12/22 11:15:29 [emerg] 14465#0: bind() to [::]:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
2014/12/22 11:15:29 [emerg] 14465#0: bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
2014/12/22 11:15:29 [emerg] 14465#0: bind() to [::]:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
2014/12/22 11:15:29 [emerg] 14465#0: still could not bind()
2014/12/22 11:16:14 [error] 14447#0: *3 directory index of "/var/www/mysite.com/public_html/" is forbidden, client: 41.150.139.252, server: mysite.com, request$
```

Comment: Have a look at the logs to see what's causing the error.

Comment: I have a hunch that `mysite.com/public` isn't the right path. What directory does `mysite.com` point to, and where is laravel?

Comment: @BobBrown how and where do I see the logs?

Comment: @mopo922 The directory is `/var/www/mysite.com` and laravel is installed directly in there

Comment: Thx @JoshHarington , now where is the document root, according to your apache/nginx config?

Comment: @JoshHarington:  You're going to need to look at the documentation for your installation, or perhaps someone with more experience than I can tell you.

Comment: @BobBrown see updated post with error log

Comment: @mopo922 the root is set to `/var/www/mysite.com/public_html/`

Comment: @JoshHarington: See whether this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19285355/nginx-403-error-directory-index-of-folder-is-forbidden  (I'm not sure it will because I'm in unfamiliar territory, but it looks right to me.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your responses in the comments, I think there's a disconnect as to where stuff IS and where you expect it to be.

You said: "The directory is `/var/www/mysite.com` and laravel is installed directly in there"

So I would expect something like this:

```
/var/www/mysite.com/
    app/
    public/
    vendor/
    etc...
```

Then you said: "the [webserver] root is set to `/var/www/mysite.com/public_html/`"

So when you go to `mysite.com` in your browser, it points at `/var/www/mysite.com/public_html/`, and `mysite.com/public` points to `/var/www/mysite.com/public_html/public/`, which doesn't seem like what you want.

**Try changing the web server root to point to `/var/www/mysite.com/public/` (Laravel's "public" dir).**