# Ruby on rails application return 403 error deploy in ubuntu with unicorn and nginx?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nginx, unicorn, http-status-code-403

I deploy a `ruby on rails` application in ubuntu. I have test my application with `RAILS_ENV=production rails s`, everything is ok. But with `unicorn` and `nginx`, I got 403 error.

here is the error log:

```
2015/01/21 16:04:48 [error] 12432#0: *1 directory index of "/home/roger/ruby_workspace/hello_app/public/" is forbidden, client: 192.168.44.1, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "192.168.44.131"
```

ll /home/roger/ruby_workspace/hello_app/public/ return

```
drwxrwxr-x  2 roger roger 4096  1月 13 14:55 ./
drwxrwxr-x 14 roger roger 4096  1月 19 22:30 ../
-rwxrwxr-x  1 roger roger 1564  1月 13 14:55 404.html*
-rwxrwxr-x  1 roger roger 1547  1月 13 14:55 422.html*
-rwxrwxr-x  1 roger roger 1477  1月 13 14:55 500.html*
-rwxrwxr-x  1 roger roger    0  1月 13 14:55 favicon.ico*
-rwxrwxr-x  1 roger roger  202  1月 13 14:55 robots.txt*
```

this is part of my nginx.conf:

```
server {
    listen 80 default deferred;
    root /home/roger/ruby_workspace/hello_app/public/;
    try_files $uri/index.html $uri @hello_app;
    client_max_body_size 128M;
    keepalive_timeout 5;

    access_log logs/host.access.log main;

    location @hello_app {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header HOST $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;
        #proxy_pass http://hello_app;
    }

    error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure what you have right permission for `nginx` user for your app directory?

Comment: @Зелёный how can I know this?

Comment: I think that nginx also need user as config in nginx.conf.

Comment: try change `user username;` directive in `nginx.conf` to same linux user `roger` in your case and realod all.

Comment: @Sanjiv you mean add `user roger` in `nginx.conf`?

Comment: @Зелёный just now, I add `user roger` to `nginx.conf` and `sudo service nginx restart`, it still return 403

Comment: @Зелёный  Can you see the permission of your app and ngnix.conf?

Comment: @Sanjiv it is not my question, i never use `home` directory for rails app.

Comment: @Sanjiv my rails app `hello_app` is `775`, my `nginx.conf` is `644`

Comment: You can use this as ref: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19285355/nginx-403-error-directory-index-of-folder-is-forbidden](Click here)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look on [this](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/master/lib/support/nginx/gitlab) Nginx configuration example as **consistent** and **fully** functional. This config describes *Nginx* proxying of *Rails app* runing on *[Unicorn](http://unicorn.bogomips.org/)* via Unix socket. Now you ready to fix your config!:-)

In order to use this config from example above, setup Unicorn to **use socket** (bit faster) or HTTP port. And make sure Unicorn starts correctly. Only after that you may continue.

Please be sure `@hello_app` is correct upstream name in your config. Currently it's definition is absent in your code:

```
upstream hello_app{
  # Update xxx.socket below:
  server unix:/home/roger/ruby_workspace/hello_app/tmp/sockets/xxx.socket fail_timeout=0;
  # Or use HTTP port here e.g.
  # server http://hello_app
}
```

Anyway it's much more easy to debug proxying, when everything behind it is working.

Just in case, make sure you have assets precompilled;-)

```
$ RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

Comment: Thanks, you do help me a log, but can you tell me what is the `xxx.socket`, now my `/home/roger/ruby_workspace/hello_app/tmp/sockets/` is empty and I do not find it in [githq](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/tree/master/tmp/sockets)

Comment: I have known what is `xxx.socket` via this post [Configuring Nginx and Unicorn](http://sleekd.com/general/configuring-nginx-and-unicorn/)