# Rails, Passenger, Nginx, I get "403 Forbidden" but why?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nginx, passenger

I am trying to run my app through Passenger-Nginx on port 5000

On my browser I get '403 Forbidden' and on my nginx error log:

> 2016/07/12 17:52:12 [error] 28924#0: *1 directory index of
>   "/var/www/cava/public/" is forbidden, client: Y.Y.Y.Y, server:
>   cava, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "X.X.X.X:5000"

On passenger root I use what I get from **passenger-config --root** but whithout the rvm.
If I use the passenger root with rvm loaded I get passenger error, but is what I did here right?

For reference my app config and my nginx.conf:

**My app config**

```
server {


    listen 5000;

    listen [::]:5000;

    server_name cava;

    root /var/www/cava/public;
    #try_files $uri/index.html $uri @app;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    #index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    #location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        #try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    #}
}
```

My **nginx.conf**

```
user www-data;
worker_processes 4;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
    # multi_accept on;
}

http {

    passenger_root /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/locations.ini;
    passenger_ruby /home/tasos/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/bin/ruby;


    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;


    ssl_session_cache  builtin:1000  shared:SSL:10m;
    ssl_protocols  TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;

    server {

        passenger_enabled on;


        listen 443 ssl;

        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index index.html index.htm;

        ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/1_beast.smartupweb.com_bundle.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/smartup1.key;
        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
        ssl_ciphers ALL:!DH:!EXPORT:!RC4:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:!LOW:!aNULL:!eNULL;

        #location / {
         #       try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        #}
}
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Nginx 403 error: directory index of \[folder\] is forbidden](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19285355/nginx-403-error-directory-index-of-folder-is-forbidden)

Comment: What is the output of `ls -lad /var/www/cava/public`?

Comment: @mudasobwa 
The output is `drwxrwxr-x 5 tasos tasos 4096 Jul  5 15:18 /var/www/cava/public`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message stated:

> directory index of "/var/www/cava/public/" is forbidden

which means that your folder has no `index` file, or the file that is to be treated as index.

I am not familiar with Passenger, but if you’ll try to put there `index.html` file with content `<h1>Hello World</h1>`, it will be likely shown.

---

The below is not directly related to this problem, but I’ll leave it here for the sake of consistency.

#### Solution 1

First, determine what user your `nginx` runs as

```
ps ueax|grep 'nginx: worker'|grep -v grep|cut -f1 -d' '
#⇒ www-data
```

or it might be `nobody`, but in your case it’s `www-data` according to your `conf` file.

Change permissions on `/var/www/cava/public`:

```
sudo chown -R www-data /var/www/cava/public
```

Retry, it should work now.

#### Solution 2

Make your `nginx` [be running as your user](http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#user). At the very top of `conf` change:

```
- user www-data:
+ user tasos;
```

The latter one is probably more handy for development.

Comment: I tried both and neither worked. Thank you for your answer though. Do you have any more ideas?

Comment: You were absolutely right, I did as you said and I saw the "Hello world". I guess I copied a config that was not for rails. Do I need now to put a link in there for my "real" index or what? Or maybe you don't work with rails?

Comment: This is unlikely Rails issue; it sounds like Passenger failed to serve Rails application. I would google for Passenger setup, but as I already have said, I am unable to help with Passenger, sorry for that.

Comment: I'm running into the same issues and I'm able to edit the "Welcome to Nginx!" `index.html` and see the changes in the browser. The problem is, I'm not sure why it's not reading my `index.html.erb` files from all of my views in my rails app. Do you know if i need to make a custom `index.html` for my site?