# Nginx + Passenger - 403 Forbidden - Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, nginx, passenger, http-status-code-403

I am setting up Rails application on AWS Ubuntu 16.04 LTS using Nginx & Passenger. I am getting **403 Forbidden** error. I have checked permission and ownership but it seems like it is not working.

Ruby version: 2.5.1 .

***Nginx.conf***
Under `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` I am using `deploy` user. I have not changed anything other than `user deploy` in this file. Here is snippet:

```
user deploy;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
        worker_connections 768;
        # multi_accept on;
}
```

**Passenger.conf** : Changed `passenger_ruby` path in this file. I am using rvenv

```
passenger_root /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/locations.ini;
passenger_ruby /home/deploy/.rbenv/shims/ruby;
```

**sites-enabled/default**: In here I have removed everything and following

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;

        server_name ec2-xx-xx-xxx-xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com
        passenger_enabled on;
        rails_env    production;

        root /var/www/html/app-name/current/public;

        # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        #server_name _;
        # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;

        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }
```

**Permission on app**
[image]
[image]

Note: I am also tried setting the permission 777 `chmod 777 -R app-name`, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19553907/403-forbidden-on-rails-app-w-nginx-passenger

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38333890/rails-passenger-nginx-i-get-403-forbidden-but-why