# All routes returning 404 except '/'

Tags: laravel, nginx, laravel-5

I have successfully installed a laravel application on a nginx server running on arch linux. However when I try to view the app in web browser all routes return 404 except the default '/'. I know this because I have make:auth but I can't reach the register and login page.

I followed instructions I found via Google and created two folders, `sites-available` and `sites enabled` in `/etc/nginx/`. I then created a config file for laravel app in `/etc/nginx/sites-available` called `niko` in sites available and symlinked to it like so `ln --symbolic /etc/nginx/sites-available/niko /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/niko`.

Here are the contents of my configuration file `/etc/nginx/sites-available/niko`.

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  niko;

    #charset koi8-r;

    #access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;

    location / {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html/niko/public;
        index  index.html index.htm index.php;
    }

    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            root /usr/share/nginx/html/niko/public;
            include fastcgi.conf;
    }
    }
```

In my `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` I have this line just above the closing `}` of the `http {}` block:
 `include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;`
When I check in the nginx error log(`/var/log/nginx/error.log`) I find this entries:

```
2019/06/14 10:59:22 [error] 5429#5429: *3 directory index of "/usr/share/nginx/html/niko/" is forbidden, client: 192.168.1.101, server>
2019/06/14 10:59:36 [error] 5429#5429: *3 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/niko/public/login" failed (2: No such file or directory), clie>
2019/06/14 10:59:36 [error] 5429#5429: *3 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/niko/public/login" failed (2: No such file or directory), clie>
2019/06/14 10:59:38 [error] 5429#5429: *3 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/niko/public/login" failed (2: No such file or directory), clie>
2019/06/14 10:59:38 [error] 5429#5429: *3 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/niko/public/login" failed (2: No such file or directory), clie>
2019/06/14 11:26:53 [error] 5429#5429: *7 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/niko/public/login" failed (2: No such file or directory), clie>
2019/06/14 11:26:53 [error] 5429#5429: *7 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/niko/public/login" failed (2: No such file or directory), clie>
2019/06/14 11:27:01 [error] 5429#5429: *7 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/niko/index.php/login" failed (2: No such file or directory), c>
2019/06/14 11:27:01 [error] 5429#5429: *7 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/niko/index.php/login" failed (2: No such file or directory), c>
2019/06/14 11:27:04 [error] 5429#5429: *7 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/niko/index.php/login" failed (2: No such file or directory), c>
2019/06/14 11:27:04 [error] 5429#5429: *7 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/niko/index.php/login" failed (2: No such file or directory),
```

I have been pulling out my hair for hours because I don't know where to check. I have tried several things but nothing seems to work. Your support is appreciated.

**UPDATE:**
My new `/etc/nginx/sites-available/niko` is here

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name niko;
    root /usr/share/nginx/html/niko/public;

    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";

    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    charset utf-8;

    location / {
        try_files $uri /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    error_page 404 /index.php;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ /\.(?!well-known).* {
        deny all;
  }
}
```

**UPDATE 1**: `namei -l /usr/share/nginx/html/niko/` gives:

```
f: /usr/share/nginx/html/niko/
drwxr-xr-x root root /
drwxr-xr-x root root usr
drwxr-xr-x root root share
drwxr-xr-x root root nginx
drwxr-sr-x kali root html
drwxr-sr-x kali root niko
```

Answer (score 0):

Laravel requires that you change your nginx.conf file a tiny bit for it to work properly.

Check out this example conf file that's available in the [Laravel Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/deployment#nginx).

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;
    root /example.com/public;

    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";

    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    charset utf-8;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    error_page 404 /index.php;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ /\.(?!well-known).* {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

Comment: When I use this I now get 403 forbidden.

Comment: Are you getting any useful information from the nginx logs?

Comment: Did you just copy this example conf completely or did you tailor it to your own needs?

Comment: The latest log is `2019/06/14 12:18:27 [error] 5509#5509: *3 directory index of "/usr/share/nginx/html/niko/" is forbidden,`

Comment: I edited the root directive to point to my app public folder. then restarted nginx.

Comment: Check out if this answer will help you on your way: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51879482/1308765

Comment: I have tried recommendations in the link and now I'm still stuck with the 404. It seems to me nginx takes the laravel routes without file extensions as folders. Because from the error log it complains of no such directory.
`2019/06/14 12:27:52 [error] 5546#5546: *1 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/niko/public/login" failed (2: No such file or directory),` Do you have an idea how to let laravel translate the routes or how to fix this? Thanks mate.

Comment: Could you update your question with your new nginx conf?

Comment: Could you do `namei -l /usr/share/nginx/html/niko/` as well, so we got the permission out of the way?

Comment: `f: /usr/share/nginx/html/niko/`
`drwxr-xr-x root root /`
`drwxr-xr-x root root usr`
`drwxr-xr-x root root share`
`drwxr-xr-x root root nginx`
`drwxr-sr-x kali root html`
`drwxr-sr-x kali root niko`

Comment: I don't think your nginx server has root. You should have a look at changing those permissions.

Comment: Thanks @Linus. which folder permission should I change? And what should I change them to? Thanks for your time.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194938/discussion-between-khakali-webdev-and-linus-juhlin).