# Possible to serve Django Channels app only using Nginx and Daphne?

Tags: django, nginx, django-channels, daphne

I was under the assumption that I could run a `Django Channels` app using only `Daphne` (ASGI) and `Nginx` as a proxy for my Django app to begin with.

The application would be running with `Daphne` on `127.0.0.1:8001`

However, I am running into a `403 Forbidden` error.

```
2019/03/06 17:45:40 [error] *1 directory index of "/home/user1/app/src/app/" is forbidden
```

And when I posted about that, another user mentioned

> There is no directive to pass http request to django app in your
>   nginx config

And suggested to look into `fastcgi_pass` or `uwsgi_pass` or `Gunicorn`.

Obviously Django Channels runs on `ASGI` and I am passing all requests through that right now (not to `uWSGI` then on to `ASGI` depending on the request.)

Can I serve my Django app with only `Nginx` and `Daphne`? The [Django Channels docs](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/deploying.html) seem to think so as they don't mention needing Gunicorn or something similar.

my nginx config

```
upstream socket {
    ip_hash;
    server 127.0.0.1:8001 fail_timeout=0;
}

server {

    listen 80;
    #listen [::]:80 ipv6only=on;

    server_name your.server.com;
    access_log /etc/nginx/access.log;

    root /var/www/html/someroot;

    location / {
            #autoindex on;

            # First attempt to serve request as file, then
            # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
            # try_files $uri =404;

            #proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            #proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            #proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            #proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
            #proxy_pass http://socket;
            #proxy_redirect off;
            #proxy_http_version 1.1;
            #proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            #proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";

            #proxy_redirect off;
            #proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            #proxy_cache one;
            #proxy_cache_key sfs$request_uri$scheme;
    }

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/some/fullchain.pem;
    # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/some/privkey.pem; 
    # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot

    if ($scheme != "https") {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. Try this config:

```
upstream socket {
    ip_hash;
    server $DAPHNE_IP_ADDRESS$ fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
    ...

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://socket;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    }

    ...
}
```

Where $DAPHNE_IP_ADDRESS$ - your daphne IP and port without schema(`127.0.0.1:8001`).

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I knew I wasn't crazy! I've tried implementing your above solution however I still face the same `403 Forbidden....directory index of "/path/to/app/" is forbidden` Do you have any idea why this may be?

Comment: @Trilla update your answer with the recent config. It looks like it can't proxy_pass to daphne. Maybe your requests are picking up by a different server config? And please add "error_log /etc/nginx/error.log;" to your config and check the error.log, it may tell something.

Comment: I have just updated my answer. The error logs just say `"2019/03/07 11:23:48 [error] 16642#16642: *11 directory index of "/path/to/app" is forbidden, client: xx.xxx.xx.xx, server: app.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "www.app.com", referrer: "http://www.app.com""`

Comment: I had to take out the `try_files` line completely for it to work.