# Nginx Showing Welcome Page/403 Error instead of homepage

Tags: nginx, server, vps, centos6.8

I am using CentOs 6.8

Using CloudFlare DNS in Development Mode

Nginx shows welcome page, its picking up from

> /usr/share/nginx/html

But not from:

> /home/nginx/domains/XYZDomain.com/public/

**In Directory:**

> /etc/nginx/conf.d

**2 Configurations Files:**

> default.conf
>   virtual.conf

**default.conf file output**

```
# Main Local

server {
        listen 80;
        server_name localhost;
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index index.php index.html index.htm;


        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }

        error_page 404 /404.html;
        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
                root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        }

        #
        location ~ \.php$ {
                include fastcgi_params;
                #fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;

        }

        location ~ /\. {
                deny all;
                access_log off;
                log_not_found off;
        }
        location = /favicon.ico {
                log_not_found off;
                access_log off;
        }
        location = /robots.txt {
                allow all;
                log_not_found off;
                access_log off;
        }

}
```

**virtual.conf file output:**

```
server {

            listen   80;
            #server_name  www.XYZDomain.com;
            # Now Changed to below withouth wwww.
            server_name  XYZDomain.com;
            rewrite ^/(.*) http://XYZDomain.com/$1 permanent;

            location / {

                        root   /home/nginx/domains/XYZDomain.com/public/;
                        index  index.html;

                        }

}
```

**nginx.conf file in  /etc/nginx/nginx.conf  output**

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  1;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    #default_type  application/octet-stream;
    #changed to text/html
    default_type text/html;
    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}
```

**All Directories with permissions.**

> ls -la /home/nginx/domains/XYZDomain.com

```
drwxr-s--- 6 root root 4096 Jul  1 12:54 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Jul  2 14:44 ..
drwxr-s--- 2 root root 4096 Jun 30 15:58 backup
drwxr-s--- 2 root root 4096 Jun 30 15:58 log
drwxr-s--- 2 root root 4096 Jun 30 15:58 private
drwxr-sr-x 2 root root 4096 Jul  2 15:01 public
```

I have tried modifying default.php and virtual.conf file

Can Anyone can help me what's wrong in this? I am really confused and have wasted a whole day on this.

Comment: Are you missing a `server` for "XYZDomain.com"? You seem to redirect "www.XYZDomain.com" to "XYZDomain.com", which if pointed to this host will be handled by the `server` block in `default.conf`.

Comment: @RichardSmith I changed `server_name  www.XYZDomain.com` to `server_name XYZDomain.com` in `virtual.conf`. Still, it's doing same. Sorry, I am new to this, I will try my best from what I understand.

Comment: changed     
`default_type  application/octet-stream;`
to     
`default_type  text/html;`

still same..

Comment: A good debugging step would be to disable `default.conf` and hit it again. See if you get the expected page or something else, which will let you know if it's at least picking up your `virtual.conf` file. I'm sure you already know this, but since you mentioned you are new at this, be sure to reload nginx after making config changes.

Comment: @patrick3853 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19285355/nginx-403-error-directory-index-of-folder-is-forbidden/19302688

This helped me

changing user in nginx.conf 
to root

Though, I guess it can be harmful?

Comment: @Python I've added an answer based on your updates with examples to get it fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way was to change user to `root`
but it's harmful.

**Second** is to
Transfer all the domain files into

`/var/www/html/XYZDomain.com/public`
**Instead** of `/home/nginx/domains/XYZDomain.com/public/`

and changed `virtual.conf`(in conf.d directory) file **from** 
`root /home/nginx/domains/XYZDomain.com/public;`
**to**
`root /var/www/html/XYZDomain.com/public`

**Things to take care of is:**

1. Check of extra useless Spaces
2. Copied code from the web can cause problems
3. Always run `nginx -T` to check for errors
4. Always Restart Nginx before testing
   `service nginx restart`
5. Running `tail -f /var/log/nginx/error.log` to check latest error logs
6. Make sure your web directory has access permissions
7. Toggle SELinux, It can cause issues.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like this is a permissions problem. Nginx is running as the `nginx` user, but the files are owned by `root` and do not have global read permissions, meaning the `nginx` user cannot see them.

First, **do not run ngninx as root!** This is very bad. If someone compromises your site, they could potentially have root access to the server.

There are several approaches to solving this. This easiest is to simply change the owner of the files to `nginx`:

```
chown -R nginx:nginx /home/nginx/domains/XYZDomain.com
```

*Of course, you will have to remember to do this for any new files you create*

You can also change just the group for the file to `nginx`, and make them group readable:

```
chgrp -R nginx /home/nginx/domains/XYZDomain.com
chmod -R g+r /home/nginx/domains/XYZDomain.com
```

The second approach is a little more secure, because nginx does not have write permissions and can only read the files. However, this can cause other problems if you have scripts that need to dynamically create or edit files.

There is a lot more to get into regarding permissions and web servers, with lots of security implications, which is too much to get into here. You can find plenty of information on stackoverflow.com if you are curious.

Comment: I always get 
***403 Forbidden
nginx/1.16.0***

On Changing user to **nginx**

I did that to all the directories:

```
`sudo chown -R nginx:nginx /home/nginx/*`
`sudo chown -R 0755 /home/nginx/*`

`sudo chown -R nginx:nginx /home/nginx/domains/XYZDomain.com/*`
`sudo chown -R 0755 /home/nginx/domains/XYZDomain.com/*`

`sudo chown -R nginx:nginx /home/nginx/domains/XYZDomain.com/public/*`
`sudo chown -R 0755 /home/nginx/domains/XYZDomain.com/public/*`
Plus what you said too...

Comment: On tail
> tail -f /var/log/nginx/error.log

`2019/07/03 10:25:12 [error] 26313#26313: *3 "/home/nginx/domains/XYZDomain.com/public/index.html" is forbidden (13: Permission denied), client: 142.111.2xx.1xx, server: www.XYZDomain.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "XYZDomain.com"`


Checking **/etc/passwd**
--x--
`nginx:x:498:498:nginx user:/var/cache/nginx:/sbin/nologin`
--x--


Is something wrong in here?

Comment: Selinux is Disabled

Comment: Yes, you are confusing `chown` and `chmod`. The `chown 0755` you ran tried to set the owner to the user id of 0755, which probably doesn't exist. If you want to change permissions (which is different from ownership) you use `chmod`

Comment: @Python Honestly, it looks like your permissions are all jacked up. I imagine `/home/nginx` is the home directory for the `nginx` user, in which case `nginx` would typically be the owner of all those files. I'm guessing you created the `domains/*` directory as `root`, which is why `root` became the owner. Try running **just** `chown -R nginx:nginx /home/nginx` and then try it again.

Comment: What I did was, 
I transferred all the domain files into

`/var/www/html/DOMAIN.com/public`

and changed `virtual.conf` file root directory accordingly.

Now it is working fine.
Is there anything else, I can/should/must do?

Thanks for everything.

Comment: This is a good solution. In fact, I prefer placing my root directories in `/var/www` instead of `/home` due to more restrictive permissions in the `/home` directory. There is certainly more you can do, but for a simple website, you shouldn't need to do anything else.

Comment: Exactly! plus there are many other things one must have to consider in order to reach that solution. Thanks for your support.

Answer (score 0):

[Nginx 403 error: directory index of [folder] is forbidden](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19285355/nginx-403-error-directory-index-of-folder-is-forbidden/19302688)

Changing User in `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` 
from 
`nginx` to `root`

helped...

is it harmful? or security risk? Now thats a question...

Thanks StackOverFlow & Thanks Community

Love