# jwilder/nginx giving 403 permission forbidden

Tags: docker, nginx, reverse-proxy, jwilder-nginx-proxy

I'm trying to serve multiple containers with a static index.html file with a nginx reverse proxy

I've tried to follow the documentation [here](https://github.com/jwilder/nginx-proxy) to create a default location

```
location / {
  root   /app;
  index  index.html;
  try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
}
```

If I check my default.conf in my container with

```
$ docker-compose exec nginx-proxy cat /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
```

I get this result:

```
server {
        server_name _; # This is just an invalid value which will never trigger on a real hostname.
        listen 80;
        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log vhost;
        return 503;
}
# xx.example.services
upstream xx.example.services {
                                ## Can be connected with "nginx-proxy" network
                        # examplecontainer1
                        server 172.18.0.4:80;
}
server {
        server_name xx.example.services;
        listen 80 ;
        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log vhost;
        location / {
                proxy_pass http://xx.example.services;
                include /etc/nginx/vhost.d/default_location;
        }
}
# yy.example.services
upstream yy.example.services {
                                ## Can be connected with "nginx-proxy" network
                        # examplecontainer2
                        server 172.18.0.2:80;
}
server {
        server_name yy.example.services;
        listen 80 ;
        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log vhost;
        location / {
                proxy_pass http://yy.example.services;
                include /etc/nginx/vhost.d/default_location;
        }
}
```

If i check the content of /etc/nginx/vhost.d/default_location it is exactly what I typed in the beginning, so that's fine

However when i go to xx.example.services  I get a 403 forbidden.

To my understanding this means that no index.html file was found, but if i exec into my container and cat app/index.html it does exist!

I've checked that all my containers are on the same network.

I'm running my container with this command

```
docker run -d --name examplecontainer1 --expose 80 --net nginx-proxy -e VIRTUAL_HOST=xx.example.services my-container-registry
```

**Update**
I checked the logs of my nginx-proxy container and found this error message:

> [error] 29#29: *1 directory index of "/app/" is forbidden..

Tried removing $uri/ as per [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19285355/nginx-403-error-directory-index-of-folder-is-forbidden) but this just left me with redirect cycles. Right now I'm trying to see if I can set the correct permissions, but I'm struggling

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My issue was a basic misunderstanding that the reverse proxy can reach into the filesystem of my containers as stated by jwilder himself [here](https://github.com/jwilder/nginx-proxy/issues/270).

Therefor the default location on the reverse proxy is unnecessary in my case. Instead I can simply let it point to my container, and have the nginx config in my container determine the location of my app.

Answer (score 0):

Hi its simple your containers is missing /app/index.html inside them

Comment: then how can i see the content when i write "docker exec examplecontainer1 cat app/index.html"?

Comment: and config of that container or permissions of files?