# directory index of /var/www/html forbidden

Tags: docker, nginx

I am using the following file copied at `/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf`

```
server {
    listen 80;
    root /var/www/html/public;
    index index.php index.htm index.html;

    location / {
        try_files $uri /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location ~ ^/index\.php(/|$) {
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $realpath_root;

        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        return 404;
    }
}
```

It is giving me the following error in log

***7 directory index of "/var/www/html/" is forbidden, client: 172.17.0.1, server: _, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost:8080"**

Trying to debug but no clue.

My files are under `www-data:www-data`

[image]

I am using a docker image from php:7.4-fpm if it is related.

```
FROM php:7.4-fpm

WORKDIR /var/www/html

RUN export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y nginx procps

COPY infrastructure/nginx/default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

COPY infrastructure/entrypoint.sh /etc/entrypoint.sh

EXPOSE 80

ENTRYPOINT ["sh", "/etc/entrypoint.sh"]
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: How are you running the image?  If your container should be running Nginx, why did you base it off of a PHP-FPM image?

Comment: Because I want to avoid tuning PHP rather take the base default image and get all extensions installed and configured.

Comment: @DavidMaze this is how i am running container `docker run -p 8080:80 -v /path/to/project:/var/www/html test-php`

Comment: The `ls -al` you posted is done from your host or inside your container ?

Comment: I think it is due to the fact that your `www-data` from your host does not have the same `uid:gid` than the one from your container.

Comment: @MichéeLengronne inside container.

Comment: Do you have an index file inside of your public folder?

Comment: Ok, so forget my previous comment. In your `nginx.conf` what is the `user` directive ?

Comment: @aynber yes its there.

Comment: @MichéeLengronne `user www-data;` this is from `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`.

Comment: Does this issue help you ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19285355/nginx-403-error-directory-index-of-folder-is-forbidden

Comment: @MichéeLengronne nope, just tried it again with the same configuration as mentioned in that answer, still 403

Comment: The error message means that there is no `index.html` file in `/var/www/html`. The configuration file in your question sets the root to `/var/www/html/public` which means that it's not the configuration that Nginx is using. Use `nginx -T` (uppercase `T`) to view the entire configuration that Nginx is reading.

Comment: @RichardSmith Yes that was the issue. There was a default configuration set in `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` that was being executred`. nging -T helped to identify. THanks

Answer (score 4):

It says "directory index...is forbidden" NOT that it does not have permission. If you were to provide the URL of one of the files, e.g. http://example.com/composer.json , nginx should happily return the content to your browser. If you explicitly want to browse the files in a directory then this [must be explicitly enabled in the nginx config](https://nginxlibrary.com/enable-directory-listing/).