# certbot certicate secure not working on Deployed App using Ubuntu

Tags: laravel, ubuntu

I am using ubuntu-20.04 for Laravel-8 application. When I deployed to the server I ran this:

```
sudo certbot --nginx -d example.com -d www.example.com

sudo certbot renew --dry-run
```

After showing success, I still got this on the browser:

> Not Secure: Your connection is not private

The folder in sites-available is like this:

```
server {
    root /var/www/html/myapp;
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
    server_name example.com;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}
server {
   if ($host = example.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot

    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name example.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
}
```

How do I get this resolved?

Thanks

Comment: do you restart nginx service with `sudo service nginx restart` ?

Comment: @Enver - now have 404 forbidden nginx/1.18.0 (Ubuntu). Error log is *21 directory index of "/var/www/html/myapp/" is forbidden, client: 167.248.133.56

Comment: check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19285355/nginx-403-error-directory-index-of-folder-is-forbidden

Comment: @Enver - I also observe that it's like it's still pointing to /var/www/html/index.nginx-debian.html instead of /var/www/html/myapp

Comment: I think your config file doesn't compiled by nginx. Where is your file you thought edited.